# c# Export Object Into New A Type Of Files

Tags: c#, export

i will explain by an example, a PSD file is a file where photoshop save a project, a DOC file is a file where Office Save a Document...

I am making an application where i work with object and i want to export my object into a new type of files (for exemple TQA : Test Question Answer), and i want my application to be the only program that can open that file.

```
static class TestQuestionAnswer
{ 
    public string Question;
    public string Answer;

    //...initiating of the Question and Answer

    //...Exporting the object to a TQA file..??
}
```

any ideas ?

Comment: i thought about exporting the files into XML files (serialization) and i made some search and found CSV files, but when i open a doc file with Notepad it is crypted !! and this is what i exactly want...! any ideas are welcome

Comment: If what you want is an encrypted format, you would have to set up an encrypting (for writing) and unencrypting (for reading) system. There are tons of options to do that (you might even create your own encryption). Here you have a link which you might find useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-decrypt-string-in-net

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Binary Formatter

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

public class App 
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() 
    {
        Serialize();
        Deserialize();
    }

    static void Serialize() 
    {
        // Create a hashtable of values that will eventually be serialized.
        Hashtable addresses = new Hashtable();
        addresses.Add("Jeff", "123 Main Street, Redmond, WA 98052");
        addresses.Add("Fred", "987 Pine Road, Phila., PA 19116");
        addresses.Add("Mary", "PO Box 112233, Palo Alto, CA 94301");

        // To serialize the hashtable and its key/value pairs,   
        // you must first open a stream for writing.  
        // In this case, use a file stream.
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Create);

        // Construct a BinaryFormatter and use it to serialize the data to the stream.
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        try 
        {
            formatter.Serialize(fs, addresses);
        }
        catch (SerializationException e) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to serialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
            throw;
        }
        finally 
        {
            fs.Close();
        }
    }


    static void Deserialize() 
    {
        // Declare the hashtable reference.
        Hashtable addresses  = null;

        // Open the file containing the data that you want to deserialize.
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Open);
        try 
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            // Deserialize the hashtable from the file and  
            // assign the reference to the local variable.
            addresses = (Hashtable) formatter.Deserialize(fs);
        }
        catch (SerializationException e) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to deserialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
            throw;
        }
        finally 
        {
            fs.Close();
        }

        // To prove that the table deserialized correctly,  
        // display the key/value pairs. 
        foreach (DictionaryEntry de in addresses) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} lives at {1}.", de.Key, de.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Example taken from 
**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5sbs8z9.aspx**

Comment: is there a way to reconstitute the object from the binary file without knowing the class that the object was created from !

Comment: @CarterNolan is not trivial but then there is always people with too much free time

Comment: so i want to chose between XML serialization and Binary serialization, what do you guys suggest ?

Comment: @CarterNolan according to this examples XML Serilization produces "plain text" output http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa.aspx making it easy for any body to read the contes of your output

Answer (score 0):

Refer thru below  codeproject article.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17468/BizDraw-framework-for-NET

You might get the better reference for your application from the above link.
Hope it'll help you out.